# Яка різниця між словами "треба" і "потрібно"?

Tags: вибір-слова

Коли яке з цих двох слів вживати, - "треба", "потрібно". Намагався розібратись із цим запитанням, натрапив на цей <s>[допис](http://zkan.com.ua/navchannja/u-chomu-riznicja-mizh-slovami-treba-i-potribno.html).</s> Але він не підкріплений джерелами.

РЕД: як виявилось мене ледь не звів на манівець автопереклад російськомовного обговорення. Тому переходити за посиланням не варто, а питання відкрите.

Comment: Очевидно, що [ця сторінка](http://zkan.com.ua/navchannja/poganenkim-odnochasno-vid-travi-i-vid-ckuvannja.html) є результатом неякісного автоматичного парсингу і перекладу [цієї](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2223662-melkotravchatyj-odnovremenno-ot-travy-i-ot-travli-kak-takoe-vozmozhno.html). Так само і [допис, на який Ви посилаєтеся,](http://zkan.com.ua/navchannja/u-chomu-riznicja-mizh-slovami-treba-i-potribno.html) є автозгенерованим на основі [цього](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1269229-v-chem-raznica-mezhdu-slovami-nado-i-nuzhno.html). Тобто той допис про російську мову.

Comment: У словнику sum.in.ua немає позначок "розмовне" біля обох слів.

Comment: Обидва слова однаково прийнятні в літературній мові, але «потрібно» майже не вживається в розмовній. В такому сенсі, «треба» справді більш розмовне, ніж «потрібно».

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Здається (якщо не розглядати [інші значення слова «треба»: «жертвоприношення», «релігійний обряд», «плата священикові»](http://sum.in.ua/s/treba) — і не загострювати увагу на тому, що «потрібно» має споріднений прикметник «потрібний», а «треба» — ні), це просто синоніми, різниця майже відсутня.

На відміну від російської (де «[необходимо](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE)» є літературним, а «[надо](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE)» є розмовним), в українській мові і «[треба](http://sum.in.ua/s/treba)», і «[потрібно](http://sum.in.ua/s/potribno)» є літературними. Хоча, можливо, якийсь додатковий наліт книжковості чи формальності слово «потрібно» й має.

В частотних словниках MOVA.info бачимо таку статистику: [художня проза](http://www.mova.info/cfq.aspx?fdid=hproz) — 7486 «треба», 339 «потрібно»; [публіцистика](http://www.mova.info/cfq.aspx?fdid=publicist) — 2505* «треба», 2456 «потрібно»; [за темою «Ендокринологія»](http://www.mova.info/cfq.aspx?fdid=endokrin) — 21 «треба», 45 «потрібно». Здається, люди тяжіють до використання «потрібно» у випадках більш офіційного стилю мовлення (а також у випадку перекладів з російської, коли розмовність російського «надо» підсвідомо переноситься на українське «треба»), а в інших — до «треба».
<sub>* Насправді — більше ніж 2505, бо частина випадків вживання «треба» в ролі присудкової форми там помилково відмічена як «ім. ж. р.».</sub>

Comment: Цікаво було б подивитись аналіз суб'єктів що відносяться до цих слів у їх контексті. Можливо саме суб'єкт визначає яка форма краще - наприклад потрібно широкому колу невстановлених осіб, треба першій особі?

Comment: @hutorny, цікава думка. Можливо. Але важко перевіряти, це, мабуть, треба вручну аналізувати кожне речення (автоматично найчастіші слова поруч виходять ось такі: [для «треба»](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=треба), [для «потрібно»](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=потрібно) — але це ні про що не каже: «вам», «нам», «їм»).